# Javascript Regex to select text between first colon and optionally either end of line or a second colon

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been having trouble writing a Regex to grab text starting with a colon and getting everything that follows along with optionally ending when another colon is found. It's for emoji markdown autocompletion. So typing

- ':smil' would yield 'smil'
- ':smile:some more text'  would yield 'smile'

The expression I have now just grabs everything after the first colon:

```
const myRe = /\:(.*)$/g;
const result = myRe.exec(inputValue);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var re = /:([^:]*)/;
```

and grab captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pN8tY5/2)

Comment: nice. yeap that did it.